# Каcтомный путь до .pypirc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Файл `.pypirc` задаёт настройки для того, чтобы пушить пакеты в registry. Но он может находиться только в `$HOME`. Как установить кастомную директорию для нахождения `.pypirc`, а не домашнюю?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это можно сделать путем перегрузки классов команд по умолчанию, используемых для связи с PyPI или вашим настраиваемым сервером репозитория. Это можно сделать в вашем скрипте setup.py. Пусть сначала говорит код:

```python
# this is your project's setup.py script

import os
from distutils.command.register import register as register_orig
from distutils.command.upload import upload as upload_orig

from setuptools import setup


class register(register_orig):

    def _get_rc_file(self):
        return os.path.join('.', '.pypirc')

class upload(upload_orig):

    def _get_rc_file(self):
        return os.path.join('.', '.pypirc')

setup(
    name='myproj',
    ...
    cmdclass={
        'register': register,
        'upload': upload,
    }
)
```

Заметьте, что некоторые импорты в IDE могут выделяться как ненайденные. Не стоит этого пугаться. Из консоли всё прекрасно работает:

```
$ python setup.py sdist register upload
```

учетные данные сервера будут взяты из `.pypirc` в каталоге проекта, а не из стандартного`~/.pypirc`.

Таким образом, все, что вам нужно сделать, это заменить команды `register` и `upload` на свои собственные реализации. Эти реализации переопределяют метод `_get_rc_file` с вашей собственной логикой. После этого не забудьте настроить аргумент `cmd_class` в вашей функции `setup` так, чтобы вместо стандартных классов использовались ваши собственные классы команд.

Конечно, поскольку оба класса переопределяют один и тот же метод, вы можете изменить код, например, написание класса миксина и его повторное использование и т. д. Кроме того, если вы загружаете документы **sphinx** в **PyPI** с помощью команды `upload_docs`, вам придется перегрузить его таким же образом. В любом случае, вы должны получить общее представление о перегрузке команд из приведенного выше фрагмента.